# How to create center tabs using Suitelets?

Tags: netsuite

I am very new to Netsuite and Suitelets. How to create a center tab ( I want to create a tab next to Home, Sales......etc) by using suitelets. I read the documentation. But it's not useful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create the tab, then put suitelets on it, or do you want the suitelet to create it's own tab?

You can pre-make the tab at Customization > Centers & Tabs > Center Tabs > New

Also, if you are building software on top of Netsuite, you may choose to include center tabs in your bundle, then you don't have to write code to make the tab.